# Extracting specific rows from one table to another on Excel

Tags: excel

I have a three-column table on excel to keep track of my expenditures; the first column shows what the purpose of the expenditure was, the second shows the amount and on the third I put a "P" for transactions that are still pending on my credit card. I wish to extract the rows of the transactions that are still pending to another table (same sheet) so that I can view what is still pending seperately. It should auto update i.e. new entries should be added as I add new transactions to my table and older entries should be removed if I remove the P from the main table (the transaction gets posted). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use filtering. Select the column headers (presumably A1 to C1), then click Home -> Editing (farthest section on right by default) -> Sort & Filter -> Filter.

The column headers then have a drop down menu that allow you to sort your fields alphabetically or from lowest to highest (or vice versa) or oldest to newest. Then below you can select what values to show, in this case "Pending", and only those rows will show. Bottom left of Excel will tell you how many rows out of total rows are showing too so you can quickly see how many transactions are pending.